# Is there an easy way to figure out why global spring beans are being constructed and initialized multiple times?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

My application takes a long time to start.

There are some stateful factory beans that are supposed to be global singleton beans that are being initialized multiple (6) times. These are rather large beans that take some time to initialize.

The class Config1.java contains this annotation:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ 
    "com.myapp.svc.*", 
    "com.myapp.tools.*", 
    "com.myapp.core", 
    "com.myapp.notification.*",
    "com.myapp.jdbc.*", 
    "com.myapp.spring", 
    "com.myapp.exceptions.svc", 
    "com.myapp.exceptions.svc.dao" })
```

The class AppInitializer contains this onStartup method:

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(Config1.class);
        rootContext.register(Config2.class);
        rootContext.register(Config3.class);
        rootContext.register(Config4.class);
        rootContext.register(Config5.class);
        rootContext.register(Config6.class);
        rootContext.refresh();
}
```

A sample of a class that is being initialized multiple times is this:

```
@Component("someStatefulFactory")
@DependsOn({ "configPropertiesService", "sqlDialectFactory" })
@Scope(value = "singleton", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
@Order(2)
public class SomeStatefulFactoryImpl {

    public void somefactoryMethod() {
    }

}
```

It almost appears that the @ComponentScan annotation is evaluated during the refresh() once for every call to register().

Do you have any suggestions or ideas how I can track and fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It can happen if you have multiple contexts. If you aren't supposed to have multiple contexts, you should try to clean your app configuration and make it as minimal as possible.

Comment: This gives me a place to look. there are definitely multiple contexts. These particular beans are supposed to be in the root context as singletons.

Comment: Is there a way for a spring bean to identify the context it is instantiated in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that @ComponentScan was overused and under filtered, plus the beans were being instantiated in an @Configuration factory class. The solution is to choose one model of instantiation and get the bean generation under control.